# How to Copy file from Sharepoint to local folder through python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the code which I am using to copy file from Sharepoint to local folder..File gets copied however it gets created of 1 KB and When I open it. It shows are corrupted. Can anyone guide me How do I copy file from Sharepoint to S3 Bucket ?

```
import requests


url = 'https://share.xyz.com/sites/XYZTeam-Program/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?OR=teams&action=edit&sourcedoc={2E1B5C1A-EAC9-491F-B271-36624213C364}'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

open('Data Source.xlsx', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: You need to test the status code (it has to be 2xx) of the response as something wrong could have happened. The content of your response could be the HTML error message or something else.

Comment: But I am not getting any error.

Comment: So simply print `r.status_code` and `r.content` to see what's inside.

Comment: I am getting r.status_code = 403 and r.content = b'403 FORBIDDEN'

Comment: There you go. You can't access this page. Perhaps you should authenticate.